# PHP Parse error in my PHP script

Tags: php

I've been going over this bit of code for hours and can't find the missing comma, parentheses, or quotation, etc. I'm a PHP beginner, but I'm trying - any help finding it would be amazing. The error I get is:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end of file in ... on line 235

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'CSA' );
    $page1 = get_page_by_title( 'Co-op Members' );
    $page2 = get_page_by_title( 'Recipes' );
    $page3 = get_page_by_title( 'FAQs' );
    $page4 = get_page_by_title( 'Contact Us' );
    $page5 = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );

    if ( is_page($page->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/green/page-top5.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
    <?php
    }elseif ( is_page($page1->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/green/page-top2.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
    <?php
    }elseif ( is_page($page2->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/green/page-top3.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
    <?php   
    }elseif ( is_page($page3->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/green/page-top4.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
    <?php
    }elseif ( is_page($page4->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/green/page-top5.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
    <?php
    }elseif ( is_page($page5->ID) )
    {?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('http://ycgrown.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Cherry-Tomatoes.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
<?php
    }else{
?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('http://ycgrown.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Cherry-Tomatoes.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
```

Edit: I've added the PHP tag and still receive the error - and further ideas?

Comment: At the end add `<?php } ?>`

Comment: @Brett, I made a great effort giving you plenty of advice below. Was it useful?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing PHP tags:

```
{?>
            <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('http://xyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Cherry-Tomatoes.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
<?php
        }else{
?>
            <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('http://xyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Cherry-Tomatoes.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
```

Comment: Also, a right curly brace at the end of the giant if.

Answer (score 1):

You are also missing a closing brace for the else condition

```
 }else{
?>
        <div id="page-bg" style="background: url('http://ycgrown.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Cherry-Tomatoes.jpg') no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important;">
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could do to tidy up this code. Ideally, the code at the start would go in a controller, and then your rendering would be mainly HTML with some PHP snippets.

```
<?php
// This would be best in a controller class, but for now we'll enclose
// it in its own little section
$page = get_page_by_title( 'CSA' );
$page1 = get_page_by_title( 'Co-op Members' );
$page2 = get_page_by_title( 'Recipes' );
$page3 = get_page_by_title( 'FAQs' );
$page4 = get_page_by_title( 'Contact Us' );
$page5 = get_page_by_title( 'Home' );
?>

<!-- This is your 'view layer', so keep your PHP small and concise -->
<?php if ( is_page($page->ID) ): ?>
    <div
        id="page-bg"
        class="bgnd"
        style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/green/page-top5.jpg');"
    >
<?php elseif ( is_page($page1->ID) ): ?>
    <div
        id="page-bg"
        class="bgnd"
        style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/green/page-top2.jpg');"
    >
<?php elseif ... ?>
```

Thus, each PHP `if` or `elseif` (or indeed any statement) only takes up a single line, making it much easier to see if your indentation is being matched. Notice that although the brace form of loops/constructs is preferred for "proper" PHP, where PHP is used in a view layer, I prefer the colon form, since it is more compact, and the end delineations are easier to scan-read than a closing brace.

Also, I've switched your inline `background` rule to `background-image`, and suggest you set the "bgnd" class thus:

```
.bgnd { background: no-repeat scroll center bottom #244714 !important; }
```

That will make things more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), and thus will save you time and effort.

Lastly I've indented the `div`s so their attributes are one per line. This is a matter of taste, but imo it's more readable, and still entirely valid as HTML. It also has the benefit that you need to do less/no horizontal scrolling in your IDE, which can make life a bit easier when debugging.